# How to get total income per month and year using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get the total income per month and Year by Grouping them using a DateTime. I almost get it but I am getting a reference error and I do knot why. ( I am using VSCode so Intellisense is not working here)

This is the error:

> error CS1061: 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: int Month, int Year>,
> Venta>' does not contain a definition for 'DetalleVenta' and no
> accessible extension method 'DetalleVenta' accepting a first argument
> of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: int Month, int Year>, Venta>'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

This is my code:

```
 public IList<PorNombreMesYAnioModel> TotalIngresoVentasPorMes()
        {
            return _context.Ventas
            .Include(a => a.DetalleVenta)
            .GroupBy(a => new {
                Month = a.FechaVenta.Month,
                Year = a.FechaVenta.Year,
            })
            .Select(q => new PorNombreMesYAnioModel{
                Month = q.Key.Month,
                Year = q.Key.Year,
                Total = q.DetalleVenta.Sum(a => a.Total)
            }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Month)
            .ToList();
        }
```

The error lies in `Total = q.DetalleVenta.Sum(a => a.Total)` , looks like I do not have access to DetalleVenta which is a related entity to `Ventas`,

**Ventas class: ( Sales class)**

```
    public class Venta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

  

    public string Nombres {get; set;}

    public string Direccion {get; set;}

    public ICollection<DetalleVenta> DetalleVenta {get;set;}
}
```

**Detalle Venta: ( sales detail)**

```
public class DetalleVenta
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ProductoId {get;set;}
    public int Cantidad {get;set;}
    public decimal Precio {get;set;}

    public decimal Descuento {get;set;}
    public decimal Subtotal{get;set;}
    public decimal Total {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Este campo es obligatorio.")]
    public int VentaId {get;set;}

    public Producto Producto {get;set;}
    public Venta Venta {get;set;}

   
}
```

PorNombreMesYAnioModel.cs

```
 public class PorNombreMesYAnioModel 
{
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public int Month {get;set;}
    public string MonthName
    {
        get 
        {
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(this.Month);
        }
    }

    public decimal Total {get;set;}
}
```

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

Tried this:

```
return _context.Ventas
        .Include(a => a.DetalleVenta)
        .GroupBy(a => new {
            Month = a.FechaVenta.Month,
            Year = a.FechaVenta.Year,
        })
        .Select(q => new PorNombreMesYAnioModel{
            Month = q.Key.Month,
            Year = q.Key.Year,
            Total =  q.SelectMany(a=>a.DetalleVenta).Sum(a => a.Total)
        }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Month)
        .ToList();
```

but gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: use linqpad to debug your linq query. https://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a mistake on the `Total = q.DetalleVenta.Sum(a => a.Total)` the `q` contains a list of `Venta`, so you need to use `SelectMany`

```
public IList<PorNombreMesYAnioModel> TotalIngresoVentasPorMes()
        {
            return Ventas
            .Include(a => a.DetalleVenta)
            .GroupBy(a => new {
                Month = a.FechaVenta.Month,
                Year = a.FechaVenta.Year,
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(q => new PorNombreMesYAnioModel
            {
                Month = q.Key.Month,
                Year = q.Key.Year,
                Total = q.SelectMany(a=>a.DetalleVenta).Sum(a => a.Total)
            }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Month)
            .ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I have updated the post, see below in the updated text.

Comment: @Blue - jjust add .AsEnumerable() to perform select in memory

Comment: I did not used yet ef core (in ef6 the query is ok), I think the group by is not fully supported, so you may need to add `.AsEnumerable` before `.GroupBy` if the error still exist

Comment: wow worked! I added `var ventas = _context.Ventas.Include(a => a.DetalleVenta).AsEnumerable();`. You solved this by adding `SelectMany` so I will be marking this as solved but modify this so others can understand well.

Comment: Anyway how `.Select` and `.SelectMany` differ?

Comment: when you want to select a Collection, not a single object, you must use SelectMany. In your case, you need to select the collection of DetalleVenta, so the use of SelectMany is a must.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0